# Python default module lookup folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a number of modules I use in my Python3 programs in Spyder and every time I want to use one of these modules I put them in the same directory as my program. But I want to know if its possible to set up these modules in a single folder so that every time I want to use them in a program I just import them and this becomes a default folder Spyder checks. That way if I want to change any of these modules I don't have to go through everywhere I have copied it and replace it and can just update the module in this one folder.

This seems to me like a basic practice many people would have and I have tried searching for it but maybe I am just using the wrong terms, so if this questions has been asked before I apologize.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general Python question, not specific to Spyder.

Python searches for modules to import in the locations specified by the `PYTHONPATH` [environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables):

> **PYTHONPATH**
>
> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the same as the shell’s `PATH`: one or more directory pathnames
>   separated by `os.pathsep` (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on
>   Windows). Non-existent directories are silently ignored.

Or you can add the module location to [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20path#sys.path) in your script, before you import the module(s), using `sys.path.append`.

Comment: Thanks Nekomatic I was able to add the path using sys.path.append()